# "Your WMP is an old version" on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-media-player

On my Ubuntu 8.10, I am trying to view a video on this website (http://www.nmnathletics.com/newMediaPlayer/consolewmp.htm?oemid=23020&type=live). I have mplayer and VLC players on my Ubuntu 8.10. But it says "Your WMP is an old version. Click here to download and install the new version", which actually is an exe file.

Not using wine, any advice please?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: try upgrade your vlc and vlc plugin for firefox

Answer (score 1):

Be careful.  If a site is telling you to download an EXE file, and that site is not a download site, you may have encountered malware.  I tried to check, but the URL in your question is not valid.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry the link should be http://www.nmnathletics.com/newMediaPlayer/consolewmp.htm?oemid=23020&type=live

Comment: Looks legit, but I don't get a prompt like that on my 9.10 Ubuntu system.  What web browser (including version) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Firefox to view the website, make sure you have `mozilla-plugin-vlc` or `mozilla-mplayer` installed.